# How to Stop Accessing WordPress Page When User Login

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am trying to stop users from accessing a page when they already login. Anyone please help me how to do this. I checked it on google and all over the stake overflow but did not find any solution. Hope to get answer soon.
Thanks

Comment: You can make if conditional with is_user_logged_in function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: I want to do this for a specific page not for whole website

Comment: so just add if condition is user logged in and page id = xxx ..

Comment: Can You Please write code example for me ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code bellow , put it within your theme function.

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    if( is_page( 'page-slug' ) && is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Change page slug based on your case, you also can use page_id check these references bellow. Don't forget to **save permalink** after put that code

Reference :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/